# Prolog: findall pero para guardar solo algunas corridas

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

Hallé que para swi-prolog existe `findnsols`, sin embargo no me está funcionando.

Mi predicado `generate_color(Color)` me genera colores aleatorios para un [html](/questions/tagged/html).

Cuando intento llamarlo `N` veces y guardar los valores de las ejecuciones en una lista obtengo siempre un único resultado en vez de muchos.

```
findnsols(3, Color, generate_color(Color),Colors).
```

> Colors = ["#4c4b43"].

```
findnsols(3, Color, generate_color(Color),Colors).
```

> Colors = ["#158955"].

findnsols(300, Color, generate_color(Color),Colors).

> Colors = ["#5d67e1"].

¿Alguien sabe de alguna manera en que pueda obtener hasta las `N` soluciones que quiera en una lista?

Salida esperada:

```
findnsols(3, Color, generate_color(Color),Colors).
```

> Colors = ["#5d67e1","#4c4b43","#158955"].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema seguramente sea que tu definición de `generate_color/1` no deje más alternativas. Es decir que cada vez que la llamas obtienes un único valor.

`findnsols/4` es similar a `findall/3` pero obteniendo como máximo un número especificado de soluciones.

Por ejemplo, supongamos la siguiente definición:

```
generate_color(Color):-
  format(string(Color),"#~|~`0t~16r~6+",random(0x1000000)).
```

que no deja alternativas abiertas. Entonces puedes utilizar `length/2`+`maplist/2` para obtener una lista de N colores de la siguiente manera:

```
length(Colors, N), maplist(generate_color, Colors).
```

Ejemplo:

```
?- length(Colors, 3), maplist(generate_color, Colors).
Colors = ["#14e72f", "#e22a09", "#3cf5f6"].
```

Comment: extra;amente, genera algunos colores con un dígito extra, pero cambiándolo a random/3 funciona a la perfección. Si gustas puedes verificarlo en https://www.codewars.com/kata/56f1c6034d0c330e4a001059/prolog

Comment: El procedimiento que había puesto no rellenaba con 0 a la izquierda hasta completar los 6 dígitos hexadecimales, ahora sí lo hace